# QGIS 3 Graphical Modeler: Create Calculated Field

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

I want to automate a workflow that includes the creation of a new field in a vector point layer.  I want the new field to contain the distance between each point and the previous one, and the expression would therefore be

```
distance(($geometry),geometry(get_feature_by_id( @layer_name, $id-1)))
```

Is it possible to do this as part of an automated workflow?

Comment: You can incorporate field calculator actions into your workflow. It is available in the drop down menues within the model builder.

Comment: Did you try to add the "Field calculator" algorithm to your model with this expression ? Or are you asking how to create a model ?

Comment: You can not reference a layer in modeler via expression, so your expression cannot work, see: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30397#issuecomment-505699624

Comment: You could do an extremly sophisticated workaround using "points to path" processing algorithm and some steps inbetween calculating fields and removing them afterwards. But if your task is not part of a complex existing model I'd rather look for a PyQGIS solution. This way you could also create a processing tool (or maybe function) yourself and integrate it in the model.

Answer (score 2):

As MrXsquared suggested in his comment, you could use [PyQGIS to create a processing tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html) which you can then use in your model.

#### Example Toolbox

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication

from qgis.core import (
    QgsField,
    QgsFeatureRequest,
    QgsProcessingParameterField,
    QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer,
    QgsProcessingParameterString,
    QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
)

from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant


def calculate_distance(layer, sorting_field, field_name="DISTANCE"): 
    """ Calculates distance between points along a path """

    layer.startEditing()

    try:

        layer_provider = layer.dataProvider()
        
        if field_name not in layer.fields().names():
            layer_provider.addAttributes(
                [QgsField(field_name, QVariant.Double)]
            )
            layer.updateFields()

        fields = layer.fields().names()
        field_index = fields.index(field_name)

        sort_request = QgsFeatureRequest().addOrderBy(
            sorting_field, 
            True,   # sorted by asc
            False,  # None value at the end
        )
        feature_iterator = layer.getFeatures(sort_request)
        
        changes = {}

        last = None
        for current in feature_iterator:

            distance = 0
            if last:
                distance = last.geometry().distance(current.geometry())

            changes[current.id()] = {
                field_index: distance
            }

            last = current

        layer_provider.changeAttributeValues(changes)
        layer.commitChanges()

    except Exception:

        layer.rollBack()
        raise Exception("Script failed")


class CalculateDistance(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    
    LAYER = "LAYER"
    SORTING_FIELD = "SORTING_FIELD"
    FIELD_NAME = "FIELD_NAME"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate("Processing", string)

    def name(self):
        return "CalculateDistance"
    
    def displayName(self):
        return "Calculates distance between points along a path"
    
    def group(self):
        return "Example Scripts"
    
    def groupId(self):
        return "playground"
        
    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer(
                self.LAYER, 
                self.tr("Layer"),
                optional=False
            )
        )
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.SORTING_FIELD,
                self.tr("Sorting Field"),
                parentLayerParameterName=self.LAYER,
                type=QgsProcessingParameterField.Any,
                optional=False
            )
        )
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                self.FIELD_NAME,
                self.tr("Field Name"),
                defaultValue="DISTANCE",
                optional=False
            )
        )
    
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

        calculate_distance(
            self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.LAYER, context), 
            self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.SORTING_FIELD, context),
            self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.FIELD_NAME, context)
        )
        
        return {}
```

##### Result

[image]

##### How to add the Script to the Processing Toolbox?

1. Open QGIS
2. In your Processing Toolbox, click the Python icon
3. Then `Create New Script...`

[image]

4. Write your script, or copy/paste example above and save it
5. Finally, you will then find the script in your Processing Toolbox under `Scripts`:

[image]

#### Example Script with PyQGIS

Here the same example script but standalone and not as processing tool:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsField, QgsProject, QgsFeatureRequest
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant


layer_name = "RR_POINT_10K"
sorting_field = "OBJECTID"

field_name = "DISTANCE"


def calculate_distance(layer, sorting_field, field_name="DISTANCE"): 
    """ Calculates distance between points along a path """

    layer.startEditing()

    try:

        layer_provider = layer.dataProvider()
        
        if field_name not in layer.fields().names():
            layer_provider.addAttributes(
                [QgsField(field_name, QVariant.Double)]
            )
            layer.updateFields()

        fields = layer.fields().names()
        field_index = fields.index(field_name)

        sort_request = QgsFeatureRequest().addOrderBy(
            sorting_field, 
            True,   # sorted by asc
            False,  # None value at the end
        )
        feature_iterator = layer.getFeatures(sort_request)
        
        changes = {}

        last = None
        for current in feature_iterator:

            distance = 0
            if last:
                distance = last.geometry().distance(current.geometry())

            changes[current.id()] = {
                field_index: distance
            }

            last = current

        layer_provider.changeAttributeValues(changes)
        layer.commitChanges()

    except Exception:

        layer.rollBack()
        raise Exception("Script failed")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)

    if not layers:
        raise Exception(f"Layer {layer_name} does not exist")

    calculate_distance(layers[0], sorting_field, field_name)
```